# React app won't display PNG logo '404 (Not Found)'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to have a logo on my page change color by changing the image itself with one of another color. I've set up `this.handleMouseOver` and `..Out` and it seems to be working, hwoever I get this error in the console `GET http://localhost:8080/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)` and the logo does not show. This is my component :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Woods from './woods.jpeg';
import Logo1 from './whitestar.png';
import Logo2 from './orangestar.png';

export default class Splash extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            imgSrc: { Logo1 } 
            //this.toggleShowHome = this.toggleShowHome.bind(this);
        }
        this.handleMouseOver = this.handleMouseOver.bind(this);
        this.handleMouseOut = this.handleMouseOut.bind(this);
    }

    toggleShowHome(property){
        this.setState((prevState)=>({[property]:!prevState[property]}));
        this.props.triggerClickOnParent();

     }

    handleMouseOver() {
        this.setState({
            imgSrc: { Logo2 }
        });
    }

    handleMouseOut() {
        this.setState({
            imgSrc: { Logo1 }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div id='Splashwrapper'>
                <img src={Woods}></img>
                <img id='logoc' onMouseOver={this.handleMouseOver} onMouseOut={this.handleMouseOut} src={this.state.imgSrc} onClick={this.toggleShowHome.bind(this,'showSquareOne')}></img>
            </div>    
        );  
    }
}
```

Why I'm I getting this error? Is this a Webpack Dev Server issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your state to:

```
this.state = {
    imgSrc:  Logo1 
}
```